# Mono: can my GTK-app be executed on Windows-64bit?

Tags: mono, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I have created an Application in Linux 64bit with MonoDevelop, GTK#2 as GTK2-Project.

I am able to make an executable, the platform-target is "AnyCPU" (I have removed Posix references and GetText()-support), but I have also tried "x64".

1. This executable can be executed on Linux 64bit (terminal: mono App.exe)
2. This executable can be executed on Windows 32bit (terminal: mono App.exe)
3. This executable CANNOT be run on Windows 64bit (terminal: mono App.exe)
   brings error:

`Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: libglib-2.0-0.dll`

I have installed the `GTK+ for Windows Runtime Environment` on both machines, Windows 32bit and Windows 64bit.

In fact I have found this DLL `libglib-2.0-0.dll` on the GTK/bin-path and also have copied it to my executable-folder, even though it is set in the PATH environment variable.

Anyway, I get the same error message, but only in Windows 64bit.

Do I have a chance of making my GTK app to be running with Windows 64bit?

Is there a different `libglib-2.0-0.dll` for Windows x64 and how can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to run a Gtk# 2 application on 64-bit windows, but it requires a bit of work. It appears you've already obtained the necessary .Net assemblies, and the native Win64 Gtk+ DLLs that are needed, but you also need an additional set of 64-bit native "glue" DLLs. I have not yet found a good source for these in pre-compiled form in any of my searches, but it is possible to build them from the gtk-sharp source.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that there is a way to get a copy of the "glue" DLLs for Win64 that I have already compiled. They're included in our "APSIM Next Generation" software product, which is freely available but requires registration. Go to <http://www.apsim.info/Products/ProductRegistration.aspx> then select "APSIM" as the product and "Next Generation (Windows)" as the version. This will give you access to the installer, and the installed software will include the DLLs you need. I really ought to make these available on our github site as a public service, but I haven't done so yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer!
I nearly lost all my hope.

I will check this out and come back with a reply and set your reply as solution accordingly.

Comment: Hi Eric, installed your app but by no means found something like "libglib-2.0-0.dll".
Which kind of DLLs do you exactly mean?

I am looking for the GTK2 dlls for Win64 and currently using these ones (local references inside my project):

`System.dll`
`System.Data.dll`
`atk-sharp.dll`
`gdk-sharp.dll`
`glib-sharp.dll`
`gtk-sharp.dll`
`Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll`

The original error message is:

`Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: libglib-2.0-0.dll`

Comment: The installer should have created a folder named something like C:\Program Files\APSIM2018.10.23.3165 (the numbers will vary depending on the version you got). This will have a Bin sub-folder within it with all the necessary DLLs (including libglib-2.0-0.dll), along with a bunch of others you won't need. For the most part, you'll need those with a name starting with "lib", and those with "sharp" somewhere in the filename.

Comment: Oh, and also gtkdotnet.dll and Mono.Cairo.dll. There are around 40 DLLs in total for Gtk# support.

Comment: Hi Eric,
I am on Win 10 64bit here.
The root folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\APSIM710-r4158` was created.
Below this folder I have the subfolders `Documentation`, `Examples`, `Model`and `UserInface`.
No `bin` in here.
The program runs though (pretty nice GUI, btw).
The executable is located in in `.\Model\Apsim.exe`.
Under Model I have some DLL's, but none of the one you mentioned.

Comment: Same installation structure on Win7 64bit.

Comment: Here are all the DLL's within their folder structure I've found:
https://pastebin.com/4KiW68GE

Comment: Ah, you've picked up the wrong version of APSIM. We're making a range of architectural changes, including moving from WIndows 32-bit C++ and Fortran to C# with a cross-platform Gtk# GUI. We're still in a transitional stage, so the Win32 product remains the primary version. To get the Gtk# version, you must select "Next Generation (Windows)" from the product registration page. The 7.10 version won't help you at all with Gtk, and would only be of use to you if you want to run agricultural simulation models.